# How do I install Sheetmaker?

Tags: 11.04, installation

[image]

Sheetmaker generates Moviesheets and similar coversheets for TV-Shows.

I would like to install Sheetmaker, but it looks a bit complicated for me.

I have downloaded and followed the installation instructions from :

- http://www.users.on.net/~garstev99/wdtv/installation.html 
  and also from this source:
- http://wdtvforum.com/main/index.php?topic=7912.0

but have stacked on the first step - I can't run ModuleTest.pl in terminal - terminal is opening for 1-2seconds and then closing without any results.

I'll be very appreciated if someone could help me to execute this program.

[Related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54550/alternative-for-thumbgen)

Comment: about that last part: please open a different topic about that (if there is not already one that covers this ;) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a challenge!

Download the compressed tar file from this [website](http://www.bunyipawonga.org/sheetmaker/index.php)

Extract the downloaded file into a sub-folder in you Downloads folder called sheetmaker.

```
cd ~/Downloads/sheetmaker
```

Now install the following perl modules:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2-perl libimdb-film-perl libxml-bare-perl perlmagick libfile-finder-perl libimage-exiftool-perl libxml-tokeparser-perl libxml-treepp-perl
```

Run a test to check that all perl modules have been installed

```
perl ModuleTest.pl
```

It should say one more module "XML::RPC" needs to be installed.  If there are any more modules to be installed - look for them in synaptic manager.

The last module "XML::RPC" isnt available in Ubuntu. N.B. there is a similar named package `libxml-rpc-perl` but this is the "RPC::XML" library.

Run the following:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::RPC'
```

Press enter for ALL questions asked -

If the final question asked is to 'enter the URL of the CPAN mirror' then enter the value `http://www.cpan.org`

Re-run

```
perl ModuleTest.pl
```

It should now just say that mediainfo needs to be installed.  You install this by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shiki/mediainfo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mediainfo
```

now check that starting the application works -

```
perl SheetMaker.pl
```

Note - it might complain of missing templates - these can be downloaded from the website you linked to.

Finally - finish off by creating a desktop launcher

create a text file call `sheetlaunch.sh` with the following contents:

```
cd /home/homefolder/Downloads/sheetmaker
perl SheetMaker.pl
```

change the permissions so that is launches

```
chmod +x sheetlaunch.sh
```

now right click the desktop and create a launcher with the command line

`/home/homefolder/Downloads/sheetmaker/sheetlaunch.sh`

Click on the default icon and navigate to the sheetmaker folder to use the correct icon.

N.B. change `homefolder` for your home folder name

if you now move the launcher to the folder `.local/share/applications` then nattys' Dash will pick it up in its search.

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to figure out the TokeParser (XML::Tokeparser) issue during the Thumbgen install (where it can't or won't install).  If the ModuleTest cannot install it for you, just install it from synaptic package manager.. search for tokeparser and perl.  The full name is libxml-tokeparser-perl.  This drove me nuts for hours before thinking of simply looking in synaptic... duh!