# How do I access my NAS from an application?

Tags: networking

I need to access my files on my NAS.

Specifically how do I access my NAS from [Sheetmaker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54502/how-do-i-install-sheetmaker) - I need to access the movies' folders through the home network ?

That's not a problem for Thumbgen in Windows, but Sheetmaker hasn't mentioned option.

For example, my movies resides on my home NAS and I need to connect it directly to my laptop everytime for making sheets and thumbnails.

It would be great to do that without odd job with direct connection.

Does someone knows any scripts or utilities for improving Sheetmaker's functionality ?

Comment: Can you access your NAS via a mounted drive e.g. via SAMBA or NFS?  i.e. can you see your NAS via the mount - /media/<mountpoint> ?

Comment: Yes, sure, I can acces it via SAMBA. I can see all my devices through the network(Ubuntu 11.04 laptop, Win7 laptop, 2 mediaplayers and NAS). In respect of another thing - /media/<mountpoint> - it's a bit not cleared for me. So far I'm not Linux guru (probably later will be :) ) Could you please specify this for me ? Then I could check it. thanks in advance

Comment: If you use Nautilus you should be able to browse to the folder /media/<NAS mount point> - if you can then you should be able to do the same with SheetMaker i.e. open the /media/<NAS mount point> folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Connect to your NAS

Assuming that you can connect to your NAS via samba:

First create a folder where you will mount the NAS

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
```

Now mount the NAS - in my case its on an IP address shown under a share called "tvshows" - connecting via a Guest account

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.1.64/tvshows /media/windows -o username=Guest,password=
```

### Navigating using Sheetmaker

Start Sheetmaker - you will be able to browse to this folder:

[image]

Double clicking "windows" will show your NAS folders, for example:

[image]